# ASP.NET Identity - custom hashing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, identity

I am trying to use a custom hashing algorithm for ASP.NET Identity from the generic one to BCrypt.

Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: "It is for .Net not .Net core." - then why is your question title "Asp Identity Core"?

Comment: it is for the namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core project

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following code should work for you:

Startup.CS:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddTransient<IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>, BCryptPasswordHasher>();
}
```

BCryptPasswordHasher.cs:

```
public class BCryptPasswordHasher : IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>
{
    public string HashPassword(ApplicationUser user, string password)
    {
        return BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(SaltPassword(user, password), 10);
    }

    public PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(ApplicationUser user, string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
    {
        if (BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(SaltPassword(user, providedPassword), hashedPassword))
            return PasswordVerificationResult.Success;

        return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
    }

    private string SaltPassword(ApplicationUser user, string password)
    {
        //TODO: salt password
    }
}
```

You are creating a class implementing IPasswordHasher, then replacing the default IPasswordHasher in Startup.cs